# Doxygen and Fortran with KIND parameters

Tags: doxygen, fortran90

I'm using Doxygen to document a Fortran code and I have variables declared such as:

```
REAL(KIND=8), PARAMETER :: myParam = 1.0_8
```

but Doxygen gets confused and seems to think `REAL` is a function and throws:

```
warning: documented function `real' was not declared or defined.
```

I have `OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN` set to `YES` so that's not the issue.

Is there a way to rectify this without having to wrap some pre-processor guard around my variables to declare them as `REAL` without the `KIND` parameter when building documentation?

Comment: I don't think the line of source code you present is the issue - doxygen runs without complaint on my Fortran projects which use the `real(kind=kind) :: ...` syntax. Also, slight Fortran nitpick: don't use literal integers as kind parameters, they are *not* portable. If you want a double precision float define `integer, parameter :: real64 = selected_real_kind(15, 307)` or `use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real64` and then use `real(kind=real64) :: ...` when defining real variables.

Comment: We don't use literals, we use a parameter from `SELECTED_REAL_KIND()`. But adding a second line of code just to illustrate the problem wasn't really worth it.

Comment: Fair enough. However, my first point still stands: doxygen can definitely handle this syntax. Can you provide more context, e.g. does doxygen given any indication as to where the error is occuring/which version of doxygen are you using? Also, can you post a minimal working example which reproduces this warning?